# What does # operator do in C++ macros?

Tags: c++, macros

I came across this macro:

`#define STR_ERROR(ecode) case ecode: return #ecode;`

What does the `#ecode` part do?

ecode is an int, and this function returns a const char*.

I'm sure that this has been answered already, but my search-foo has abandoned me. `ecode` itself is specific to this code. Searching for `c++ #` gives generic information about macros (as well as some numbered lists relating to C++).

Comment: Please add source code if possible.

Comment: It stringifies the argument. E.g. `STR_ERROR(1)` expands to `case 1: return "1";`.

Comment: *my search-foo has abandoned me* - `c++ macro what does single hash do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators):

> # operator before an identifier in the replacement-list runs the identifier through parameter replacement and encloses the result in quotes, effectively creating a string literal

**Example from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/stringizing-operator-hash?view=msvc-160#examples)**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define stringer( x ) printf_s( #x "\n" )
int main() {
   stringer( In quotes in the printf function call );
   stringer( "In quotes when printed to the screen" );
   stringer( "This: \"  prints an escaped double quote" );
}
```

Result:

```
In quotes in the printf function call
"In quotes when printed to the screen"
"This: \"  prints an escaped double quote"
```

*Google-Fu protip*: I just searched for `C++ macro #`, the Google recommended adding `operator` at the end, and those docs were on the first page.

Comment: This is not a microsoft compiler specific thing. Here's a link to a compiler independent page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried the search you suggested, and there was no suggestion to adding "operator". There was a related search to ``c macro stringify``, which I didn't recognised as having any relevance.